# Warning: attempted to generate guard with empty availability: obsoleted = 21 error

Tags: android, build, android-source, android-x86

I got this error while building Android x86 from AOSP:

```
[ 29% 3755/12860] Hidden API: out/targ...id.test.base_intermediates/javalib.jar
FAILED: out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android.test.base_intermediates/javalib.jar 
/bin/bash -c "(rm -f out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android.test.base_intermediates/javalib.jar ) && (cp \"out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/test-base/android.test.base/android_common/dex/android.test.base.jar\" \"out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android.test.base_intermediates/javalib.jar\" ) && (rm -rf out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android.test.base_intermediates/dex-hiddenapi ) && (mkdir -p out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android.test.base_intermediates/dex-hiddenapi ) && (unzip -q out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android.test.base_intermediates/javalib.jar 'classes*.dex' -d out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android.test.base_intermediates/dex-hiddenapi ) && (find out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android.test.base_intermediates/dex-hiddenapi -name \"classes*.dex\" | sort | sed 's/^/--dex=/' | xargs out/host/linux-x86/bin/hiddenapi --light-greylist=out/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/hiddenapi-light-greylist.txt --dark-greylist=out/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/hiddenapi-dark-greylist.txt --blacklist=out/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/hiddenapi-blacklist.txt ) && (out/soong/host/linux-x86/bin/soong_zip -o out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android.test.base_intermediates/dex-hiddenapi/classes.dex.jar -C out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android.test.base_intermediates/dex-hiddenapi -D out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android.test.base_intermediates/dex-hiddenapi ) && (out/soong/host/linux-x86/bin/merge_zips -D -zipToNotStrip out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android.test.base_intermediates/dex-hiddenapi/classes.dex.jar -stripFile \"classes*.dex\" out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android.test.base_intermediates/javalib.jar out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android.test.base_intermediates/dex-hiddenapi/classes.dex.jar out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/test-base/android.test.base/android_common/dex/android.test.base.jar )"
xargs: out/host/linux-x86/bin/hiddenapi: terminated by signal 4
[ 29% 3762/12860] //bionic/libc:common...ioner preprocess include [linux_glibc]
warning: attempted to generate guard with empty availability: obsoleted = 21
warning: attempted to generate guard with empty availability: obsoleted = 23
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
22:53:03 ninja failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (38:42 (mm:ss)) ####
```

What should I do?

Comment: What was the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around this on lineage using the following:

```
export CPU_SSE42=false
```

Source:

https://github.com/sonyxperiadev/bug_tracker/issues/207

You could make the following changes locally and see if they worked:

https://review.lineageos.org/c/LineageOS/android_art/+/242869